# Block touch from a service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, touch, android-service

Is there a way to block touch on ANY application from a service? I've been thinking about `getWindow()`, but that is impossible in service. Also, I've been thinking about getting current activity and then use `getWindow()`. I hope you get the point of what am I tried to achieve.

Comment: You can add a view on top using `WindowManager` and consume all the clicks yourself. This is the way those "screen lock" apps do it.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks! I get this _Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@927f07b -- permission denied for this window type_. The error occurs when I try to add view to `WindowManager` on device with Android API >= 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Medenjak I have managed to solve the problem. This solution is working on Android APIs below 23 and it's going to make the screen black and block touches until you longpress on the screen.

```
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        ImageView black = new ImageView(this);
        black.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new     WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;

        windowManager.addView(black, params);

        black.getLayoutParams().height = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        black.getLayoutParams().width = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        black.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```